# Library missing, GUI-python schedule execution using crontab

Tags: python, cron

I wanted to run python program on raspberry pi at specified time using crontab but it gives an error. Running on command Terminal, I have no problem in executing the program.

**Details Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Working_IonControllerVer3.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pyqtgraph as pg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph'
```

**Terminal**

```
$ sudo crontab -e 

39 5 * * * sh  /home/pi/Desktop/launcher.sh
```

shell script is as following

```
#! /bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:1
PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/
/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/pi/Desktop/codeVer3.py
```

Any suggestion how to fix this issue using crontab python program execution.

Comment: Maybe you want PYTHONPATH not PATH, PATH is for your shell not Python.

Comment: I have added as per suggestion PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/ result is same

Comment: Your new error seems like it's not related to the question in context. I would advise you to post that as a new question to attract better answers. A side note, do not post further questions as answers as it violates the rules of S/O. Please delete that and you can also accept my answer which solved your earlier problem to indicate its solved, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pyqtgraph` is not recognized globally then you should also be able to include the environment setting on the same line(in the same command) as the call to Python, like this as an example

```
*/1 * * * * PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages python /Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/createUpdate.py
```

Please be aware of spaces in the variable assignments.  No semicolon and no need to export variables, since declaring them before the commands already make them active for the command itself.

Following the example, set the `pyqtgraph` environment on the (command line) and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Do give me the link to the new question so i can look into it.